# Gradle on IntelliJ waits for about 20 seconds after all tasks have finished executing

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

I have a single module Kotlin project in IntelliJ IDEA with about one hundred lines of code. It loads some files, parses them, makes some calculations and shows result in console. Upon build it correctly executes task `:compileKotlin` in a few seconds but after building it waits for about 20 seconds before the Gradle process returns. As a consequence, when I make a change and reexecute the application it takes about 20 to 30 seconds from the moment when I click the Run button until the application starts executing.

If I execute the `:run` task from a command line with IDEA shut down, this IDLE pause happens after the application has finished execution. This keeps this command line unusable for those 20 seconds. This makes me believe that the problem is not with IDEA but with Gradle.

This pause does not happen always, only after some changes on source code. Changing a constant or rebuilding the same files does not usually cause the pause. Changing a property name usually does.

Versions:

- IntelliJ IDEA: IntelliJ IDEA 2021.1.2 Build #IU-211.7442.40, built on June 1, 2021
- Kotlin: 211-1.5.30-release-408-IJ7442.40
- Gradle: 7.2

Gradle output:

```
Microsoft Windows [Versión 10.0.19042.1165]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. Todos los derechos reservados.

E:\My Folder>gradlew.bat build

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 4s
6 actionable tasks: 6 executed
<=============> 100% EXECUTING [16s]
> IDLE
```

```
Microsoft Windows [Versión 10.0.19042.1165]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. Todos los derechos reservados.

E:\My Folder>gradlew.bat run

> Task :run
***********************************************************************
Console Output of my program
***********************************************************************

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 11s
2 actionable tasks: 2 executed
<=============> 100% EXECUTING [15s]
> IDLE
```

Please see that first snippet shows `BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 4s` but keeps executing `EXECUTING [16s]`, this is it has been pausing `IDLE` for 12 seconds at the moment I copied the output. Second snippet shows `BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 11s` (compilation + application execution took 11s) but keeps executing `EXECUTING [15s]`, this is it has been pausing `IDLE` for 4 seconds after the application had already finished executing at the moment I copied the output.

Comment: Could you please to run the same commands  in command line outside IDE?

Comment: Did it and got the same result, it seems to be something to do with gradle rather than IDEA. I tested both IDEA's built in command line and Windows' cmd with identical results.

Comment: Seems to have resolved on its own after IDEA auto updates

Comment: I still see the same problem on IDEA 2023.3.5. I am a Maven user, and I only use Gradle if absolutely necessary, because in IDEA it has always been slow for 15 or so years. I have no idea where the 20 extra seconds come from each single time I run a single class project.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if your problem is the same as mine, but for me, using `mavenLocal()` in the build file in connection with a huge local Maven repository is causing the problem. I created [Gradle issue #28485](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/28485) for it.